# MSMQ Storage Quotas Mismatch

Tags: msmq

Given the situation were the storage quotas are different on the send / receive servers. Which one overrides? For example the message limit on the sender is 1GB but on the receiver it's 10GB, does the queue on the receiver grow beyond 1GB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The storage quota is local. The receiver can store up to 10GB of message from ANY source, including itself. The receiver cares nothing for the storage quota on any other machine.